# Union of two sets given a certain ordering in O(n) time

Tags: algorithm, union, complexity-theory, time-complexity

> [**Note:** I am hoping this problem can be solved in `O(n)` time. If not, I am looking for a proof that it cannot be solved in `O(n)` time. If I get the *proof*, I'll try to implement a new algorithm to reach to the union of these sorted sets in a different way.]

Consider the sets:

```
(1, 4, 0, 6, 3)
(0, 5, 2, 6, 3)
```

The resultant should be:

```
(1, 4, 0, 5, 2, 6, 3)
```

Please note that the problem of union of sorted sets is easy. These are also sorted sets but the ordering is defined by some other properties from which these indices have been resolved. But the ordering (whatever it is) is valid to both the sets, i.e. for any `i, j ∈ Set X` if `i <= j`, then in some other Set `Y`, for the same `i, j, i <= j`.

**EDIT:** I am sorry I have missed something very important that I have covered in one of the comments below — intersection of two sets is not a null set, i.e. the two sets have common elements.

Comment: are those "other properties" known? It seems like you can map these indices to a sorted linear set using those properties.

Comment: Given that they are 'sets', can we assume that the items are distinct within a set (i.e. no items can appear more than once)?

Comment: Yes, the properties are known. Can you please explain what you mean by 'indices to sorted linear set'?

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, that is true.

Comment: what if two sets are different? A = {1} , B = {2}, what should the union look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert each item in the first set into a hash table.

Go through each item in the second set, looking up that value.

- If not found, insert that item into the resulting set.
- If found, insert all items from the first set between the last item we inserted up to this value.

At the end, insert all remaining items from the first set into the resulting set.

**Running time**

Expected `O(n)`.

**Side note**

With the constraints given, the union is not necessarily unique.

For e.g. `(1) (2)`, the resulting set can be either `(1, 2)` or `(2, 1)`.

This answer will pick `(2, 1)`.

**Implementation note**

Obviously looping through the first set to find the last inserted item is not going to result in an `O(n)` algorithm. Instead we must keep an iterator into the first set (not the hash table), and then we can simply continue from the last position that iterator had.

Here's some pseudo-code, assuming both sets are arrays (for simplicity):

```
for i = 0 to input1.length
   hashTable.insert(input1[i])

i = 0 // this will be our 'iterator' into the first set

for j = 0 to input2.length
   if hashTable.contains(input2[j])
      do
         output.append(input1[i])
         i++
      while input1[i] != input2[j]
   else
      output.append(input2[j])

while i < input.length
   output.append(input1[i])
```

The do-while-loop inside the for-loop may look suspicious, but note that each iteration that that loop runs, we increase `i`, so it can run a total of `input1.length` times.

**Example**

Input:

```
(1, 4, 0, 6, 8, 3)
(0, 5, 2, 6, 3)
```

Hash table: `(1, 4, 0, 6, 8, 3)`

Then, go through the second set.

Look up `0`, found, so insert `1, 4, 0` into the resulting set
(no item from first set inserted yet, so insert all items from the start until we get `0`).

Look up `5`, not found, so insert `5` into the resulting set.

Look up `2`, not found, so insert `2` into the resulting set.

Look up `6`, found, so insert `6` into the resulting set
(last item inserted from first set is `0`, so only `6` needs to be inserted).

Look up `3`, found, so insert `8, 3` into the resulting set
(last item inserted from first set is `6`, so insert all items from after `6` until we get `3`).

Output: `(1, 4, 0, 5, 2, 6, 8, 3)`

Comment: How did you insert 1, 4, 0 into the resulting set?

Comment: my only problem with this is the "uncertainty" from the partial orders. e.g. remove zeros from the example set, the union is no longer unique. Otherwise solutions is correct.

Comment: I understand your concern. But these sets will have common elements. So intersection(S1, S2) is not a null set.

Comment: @flippex17 I expanded a bit on that in my answer (this falls under "insert all items from the first set between ..." in the second bullet).

Comment: Ok I understand what you have done but I am kind of lost majorly because all you are using is a hash table which basically provides the capability of searching if an element exists in the table in `O(1)` time. But on the second instance, you deal with indices which is not possible; hence this is more of an `O(n^2)` issue rather than `O(n)`.

Comment: @flippex17 Added an implementation note with some pseudo-code.

Comment: Okay that helps. I will look for further optimizations but thanks for the heads up. Honestly, this is something similar to what I thought but wasn't able to convince if this was `O(n)` time.

Answer (score 1):

We have two ordered sets of indices A and B, which are ordered by some function f(). So we know that `f(A[i]) < f(A[j])` iff `i < j`, and the same holds true for set B.

From here, we got a linear mapping to a "sorted" linear sets, thus reduced to the "problem of union of sorted sets".

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example? I'm not convinced that this can be solved with the union of sorted sets (in O(n)).

Comment: It is essentially what you are doing in your solution, but utilizes the "known" function f(). Say we have an array of distinct integers P, so that A is the sorted set of elements on *even* positions, and B is for *odd* position elements. Then during "union of sorted sets" the condition would be something like *if (P[a[i]] < P[b[i]])*

Answer (score 0):

This also doesn't have the best space complexity, but you can try:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [4,2,79,8]

union = {}

for each in a:
    union[each]=1
for each in b:
    union[each]=1

for each in union:
    print each,' ',
```

Output:

```
>>> 1   2   3   4   5   8   79
```